# browser.driver.get will wait for angular to finish loading

Tags: protractor

browser.get will wait for angular to wait until angular page is loaded and boostrapping is done.what about browser.driver.get is this also wait till angular is loaded .Can we access angular specific locators when we load the url through browser.driver.get()

Answer (score 0):

`browser.driver.get()` would call the `get()` method of the `WebDriverJS` driver and it, of course, it would not wait for Angular to signal it's readiness. This, usually, leads to using *Explicit Waits* to wait for certain conditions to be met indicating that the page is loaded.

You can use the Angular specific locators after as usual.